# Logging in custom ant tasks

Tags: java, logging, ant

I'm creating a custom ant task, which performs an IO tasks based on the user received param(like an file write/append)

I wanted to write the task so as if the developer using it in the ant task runs it with a `-v` or `-d` flag, will output more,

I'm wondering how are the core ant tasks doing it. Are they checking the output level before printing to console or is it just done by using `java.util.logging.Logger`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow this [tutorial](http://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-writing-tasks.html#TaskAdapter).

Extract :

> Integration with TaskAdapter
>
> Our class has nothing to do with Ant. It extends no superclass and
>   implements no interface. How does Ant know to integrate? Via name
>   convention: our class provides a method with signature public void
>   execute(). This class is wrapped by Ant's
>   `org.apache.tools.ant.TaskAdapter` which is a task and uses reflection
>   for setting a reference to the project and calling the `execute()`
>   method.
>
> Setting a reference to the project? Could be interesting. The Project
>   class gives us some nice abilities: access to Ant's logging facilities
>   getting and setting properties and much more. So we try to use that
>   class:
>
> ```
> import org.apache.tools.ant.Project;
>
> public class HelloWorld {
>
>     private Project project;
>
>     public void setProject(Project proj) {
>         project = proj;
>     }
>
>     public void execute() {
>         String message = project.getProperty("ant.project.name");
>         project.log("Here is project '" + message + "'.", Project.MSG_INFO);
>     } }
> ```
>
> [...]

Comment: I'm still not convinced by the tutorial, the output is not still formatted correctly. The messages are still logged without the taskname